# pandas - expressive method for counting based on occurrences of substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'name': ['john','jack','jill','al','zoe','jenn','ringo','paul','george','lisa'], 'how do you feel?': ['excited', 'not excited', 'excited and nervous', 'worried', 'really worried', 'excited', 'not that worried', 'not that excited', 'nervous', 'nervous']})

      how do you feel?    name
0              excited    john
1          not excited    jack
2  excited and nervous    jill
3              worried      al
4       really worried     zoe
5              excited    jenn
6     not that worried   ringo
7     not that excited    paul
8              nervous  george
9              nervous    lisa
```

I am interested in the counts, but grouped by three categories: "excited", "worried", and "nervous".

The catch is that "excited and nervous" should be grouped with "excited". In fact, strings that contain "excited" should be included in a group *except* for strings like "not that excited" and "not excited". The same logic applies to "worried" and "nervous". (Note that "excited and nervous" would actually belong to both the "excited" and "nervous" group)

You can see that a typical groupby will not work and string searching will have to be flexible.

I have a solution, but wondering if you all can find a better approach in terms of being Pythonic, and/or using more appropriate methods that I may not be aware of.

### Here is my solution:

Define a function to return counts for rows that contain desired substrings AND don't contain substrings that negate the sentiment

```
def get_perc(df, column_label, str_include, str_exclude):

    data=df[col_lab][(~df[col_lab].str.contains(str_exclude, case=False)) & \
    (df[col_lab].str.contains(str_include,  case=False))]

    num=data.count()

    return num
```

Then, call this function inside of a loop, passing in the various "str.contains" arguments, and gather up the results into another DataFrame.

```
groups=['excited', 'worried', 'nervous']
column_label='How do you feel?'

data=pd.DataFrame([], columns=['group','num'])
for str_include in groups:
    num=get_perc(df, column_label, str_include, 'not|neither')
    tmp=pd.DataFrame([{'group': str_include,'num': num}])
    data=pd.concat([data, tmp])


data

      group    num
0   excited      3
1   worried      2
2   nervous      3
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this that you can think of? I did try a regular expression in "`str.contains`" to try and avoid the need for two boolean series and the "`&`". However, I couldn't do it without capture groups and this meant I had to use "`str.extract`", and that seemed to not allow me to select data in the same way.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `"excited and nervous"` counts to be both or just `excited` ?

Comment: both would be nice

Comment: In that case, you may as well edit your question.

Comment: I will recommended NLTK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

**Method 1**

1. Ignore `not` rows, and then
2. Get relevant `groups` from indicator strings.

---

```
In [140]: col = 'how do you feel?'

In [141]: groups = ['excited', 'worried', 'nervous']

In [142]: df.loc[~df[col].str.contains('not '), col].str.get_dummies(sep=' ')[groups].sum()
Out[142]:
excited    3
worried    2
nervous    3
dtype: int64
```

---

**Method 2**

```
In [162]: dfs = df['how do you feel?'].str.get_dummies(sep=' ')

In [163]: dfs.loc[~dfs['not'].astype(bool), groups].sum()
Out[163]:
excited    3
worried    2
nervous    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Good one, I was just about to post dummies_df = df['how do you feel?'].str.get_dummies(sep = ' ')
dummies_df.loc[dummies_df['not'] != 1, ['excited', 'worried', 'nervous']].sum() You beat me to it :)

Comment: @Zero I really like this "get_dummies" thing. I was using `str.contains` so that I'd still be able to group something like "excited" and "exciting" together by using regex groups like `'excited' | pumped | thrilled | excited'`. Of course this would require some lemmatization to accomplish properly. NLTK in conjunction with your approach could work nicely.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply provide your mappings and then group by the new series that the mappings yields.

```
map_dict = {'excited and nervous':'excited', 'not that excited':'not excited', 
            'really worried':'worried', 'not that worried':'not worried'}
df.groupby(df['how do you feel?'].replace(map_dict)).size()
```

Output:

```
how do you feel?
excited        3
nervous        2
not excited    2
not worried    1
worried        2
dtype: int64
```